Sign Github commit with ssh key for specifics folders only (Verified badge)

I am trying to get the "Verified" badge on my GitHub commits, but only for repositories located in a specific folder.
On my work computer, I have some personal GitHub repositories and work repositories (private GitLab).
I want to configure Git conditionally based on the folder where the repository is stored, so I don't have to manually set the Git configuration for each repository.
For example

~/work/** --> Should use my work email and doesn't need to sign commit
~/perso/** --> Should use my github mail and sign commit with ssh key


After searching, here is a quick way:
1. Generate a private/public key
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/github_id_rsa

2. Add you public key as "signed key" on your github account

Go to: https://github.com/settings/keys
Click on "New SSH Key"
On "Key type" drowndown select "Signing Key"


3. Update your .gitconfig
~/.gitconfig
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = john@company.com # Your work email 
    
[includeIf "gitdir:~/perso/"]
    path = ~/.gitconfig-github
    
# Rest of your configuration...

~/.gitconfig-github
[user]
    name = UsernameGithub
    email = 000000+user@users.noreply.github.com # your github email
    signingkey = ~/.ssh/github_id_rsa.pub
    
[gpg]
    format = ssh
[commit]
    gpgsign = true


